# How do I use data coming in via stidn pipe for fs.createReadStream

Tags: node.js

How do I use data coming in via stidn pipe for fs.createReadStream

```
fs.createReadStream('buffer_from_stdin?').pipe(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

stdin is already open but it is paused:

```
process.stdin.pipe(...)
process.stdin.resume()
```